# The Ruby version you are trying to install does not exist: ruby-2.6.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

In heroku I got this error  `The Ruby version you are trying to install does not exist: ruby-2.6.1`

but locally when I put ruby -v  I got this

```
ruby 2.6.1p33 (2019-01-30 revision 66950) [x86_64-darwin20]
```

when I do gem update bundler  I got this error

```
Updating installed gems
Updating bundler
ERROR:  Error installing bundler:
    bundler-2.5.6 requires Ruby version >= 3.0.0. The current ruby version is 2.6.1.
Nothing to update
Gems already up-to-date: bundler
```

in gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby "2.6.1"
# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails', branch: 'main'
gem 'rails', '~> 6.1.3', '>= 6.1.3.2'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 5.0'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 6'
# Transpile app-like JavaScript. Read more: https://github.com/rails/webpacker
gem 'webpacker', '~> 5.0'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.7'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use Active Model has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'
group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end
# Use Active Storage variant
# gem 'image_processing', '~> 1.2'

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 4.1.0'
  # Display performance information such as SQL time and flame graphs for each request in your browser.
  # Can be configured to work on production as well see: https://github.com/MiniProfiler/rack-mini-profiler/blob/master/README.md
  gem 'rack-mini-profiler', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.3'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
group :production do
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end
gem 'nokogiri', '~> 1.10', '>= 1.10.3'
gem 'bootsnap'

gem 'mail_form'
gem "recaptcha", require: "recaptcha/rails"
```

rbenv versions

```
      system
      2.4.0
    * 2.6.1 (set by /Users/nour/vancouver-786-limo-services/.ruby-version)
    3.1.0
```

% which -a ruby

```
/Users/nour/.rbenv/shims/ruby
/Users/nour/.rbenv/shims/ruby
/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/ruby
/usr/bin/ruby
```

Answer (score 0):

MacOS ships with an extremely outdated version of Ruby, which is on the default `PATH` and is found in `/usr/bin`. To use a newer version of the ruby/gem commands you'll need to install them. You can do so from source, use [homebrew](https://brew.sh), or use a version manager such as rvm, rbenv, or mise (all of which can be installed directly or using homebrew). Depending on which choice you made, you may also have to update your zsh/bash config files to update `PATH` so your local installation is found before the system one. If you have multiple installations you can check the order of occurrence by typing `which -a ruby`.

---

Based on the additional info you’ve provided in an edit to the question, you are already using rbenv. However, the asterisk next to version 2.6.1 shows that that’s the version of Ruby it is currently configured to use. It also shows that you have version 3.1.0 installed. You can switch to using that by typing `rbenv global 3.1.0` or `rbenv local 3.1.0` as described in the [rbenv documentation](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#installing-ruby-versions).

Comment: % which ruby                  
/Users/nour/.rbenv/shims/ruby

Answer (score 0):

Heroku does support legacy and outdated Ruby versions. See the list of Ruby versions that are supported on Heroku: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-support#ruby-versions

You will need to upgrade to at least Ruby 3.0 to run your application on Heroku. I suggest upgrading to the latest 3.3 version.

Because you have already Ruby 3.1 installed on your computer, the easiest would be to enable that version and use is.

Change the Ruby version in your `Gemfile`:

```
ruby "3.1.0"
```

and in your `.ruby-version` (if it exists):

```
3.1.0
```

I recommend the enabling Ruby 3.1 globally on your system with `rbenv global 3.1.0`. Check that the expected version is used with `ruby -v`. Update gems and bundler of that version with `gem update --system`. Install required gems with `bundle install`.

Ruby 2.6 and 3.1 are slightly different, and it might be required to make a few changes to your application. Therefore, run your test and do some manual testing. Once everything is fine, try deploying to Heroku again.

With the updated `Gemfile`, `Gemfile.lock` (and `.ruby-version`), Heroku should pick the right Ruby version on the next deploy.

Comment: The rbenv output indicates they already have Ruby 3.1. OP just needs to configure it as the usage version.